# Elegant way to get the number of .mat files in a directory

Tags: matlab, directory

Assuming I have X  `.mat`files under a directory called `my_experiment_1/data`, I know I can load them into

```
experiment1_files = dir(['my_experiments/data/*.mat']);
```

Now I would like to open them in a `for` loop with the `.name` extension of `dir`:

```
for count = 1:N
  % load data-set
  load(experiment1_files(count).name);
  ...
end
```

and perform a bunch of operations with the matrices of each file.

**Question**: what is the way to compute the number of files withing a directory in MATLAB (meaning, the number `N` in the `for`-loop above)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the specification of [dir](http://www.mathworks.ch/help/matlab/ref/dir.html) it returns an Nx1 struct where the number of items N corresponds to the number of files and folders it retrieved from the path you pass to `dir`.